# how to hide datatable when there is no data to display?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

there is a datatable in my interface. when there is no data I want to hide the entire datatable. not the columns in the datatable.

can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: You can play with the `display` attribute of the element that wraps the datatable...

Comment: if you can post the code it's better

Comment: It is better to post your code of how you tried to bind data into table as well as how to hide the table when data is not available, to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to hide the wrapping div that contains the table and its content. A real simple solution would be to use initComplete like below:

```
$('#table').dataTable({
   //your table settings here..
   initComplete : function() {
      if ($(this).find('tbody tr').length<=1) {
         $('#table').parents('div.dataTables_wrapper').first().hide();
      }
   } 
});
```

The above will hide the dataTable and all of its autogenerated content, if there are no rows holding data in its body.

Added [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZNpWQB) with example.

Answer (score 0):

set the table's CSS  `visibility: hidden` when there is no data using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you get data from serverside, you can set `$('#yourtable').css('display','none');` when checking data is null or undefined.

```
$('#yourtable').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'pagingType': 'simple_numbers',
            'searching': true,
            'autoWidth': false,
            'ajax': {
                'url' : 'your_API_Url',
                'type': 'GET',
                'headers': { 'Authorization':  'Bearer ' + currentUser.access_token },
                'data': function (data) {
                   if(data == null || data == undefined){
                        $('#yourtable').css('display','none');
                   }
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: this is working but column headers are still visible

Comment: what column header still visbile? can you take a screenshot?

Comment: yes. i added a screenshot to the question above

Comment: you can try add $('thead').css('display','none'); in ajax success to

Comment: stil getting the same result. not working

Comment: Can you put html for header in question?